# How to implement SU(2) rotation with qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, bloch-sphere, experimental-realization

Before I start, I would like to say sorry for this possibly stupid question of mine.
I just recently got into the topic of quantum computing and try me there.

I'm currently trying to display a **SU(2)** rotation using Qiskit.

```
from ibm_quantum_widgets import CircuitComposer

from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector

from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from numpy import pi
import numpy as np
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator, Pauli



qreg_q = QuantumRegister(1, 'q')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q)

clreg = ClassicalRegister(1)

...
```

After the implementations, I tried to achieve such a rotation with some matrices.
This is one of them:

[image]

```
def rn_su2_5(theta, n1,n2,n3):
    #This represents a matrix operator that will evolve() a Statevector by matrix-vector multiplication and will evolve() a DensityMatrix by left and right multiplication
    return Operator([
    [np.cos(theta/2)- 1j*n3*np.sin(theta/2), -1j*(n1-1j*n2)*np.sin(theta/2)],
    [-1j*(n1+1j*n2)*np.sin(theta/2), np.cos(theta/2)+1j*n3*np.sin(theta/2)]
    ],input_dims=(2, 1), output_dims=(2, 1))

print(rn_su2_5(pi,1,1,1))
circuit.unitary(rn_su2_5(pi,1,1,1),0)
```

Output:

```
Operator([[ 6.123234e-17-1.j, -1.000000e+00-1.j],
          [ 1.000000e+00-1.j,  6.123234e-17+1.j]],
         input_dims=(2, 1), output_dims=(2, 1))

**ExtensionError: 'Input matrix is not unitary.'**
```

I would be very happy if you could help me with this problem.

Later the rotation should also be visible on a Blochsphere.

If the code is not sufficient, I will submit it later if necessary.

Comment: For single qubits (representable in a Bloch sphere), you can use the usual rotation gates rx,ry,rz to perform special unitary rotations.

Comment: @Fation: It seems that your question has an academic background investigating physical properties under the hood. You should mention that you are aware of the possibilities to use out-of-the-box gates, but you want investigate $SU(2)$ matrices.

Comment: In fact, my question is specifically related to the use of SU(2) matrices. I know there are out-of-the-box options. But I can't use this for my further development.

Comment: It might be helpful to check what the `is_unitary_matrix` function does. It computes `A^dagger.A` and checks if it is identity matrix: [See Code here](https://searchcode.com/file/316959794/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/predicates.py/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the vector `n=[n1,n2,n3]` must have an magnitude (length) of $1$, see for example [this document](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/archive/fileadmin/lehre/teilchen/ws1011/SO3SU2.pdf) (page 8, equation 50).

I implemented a debug line that shows you wether the matrix is unitary or not. When choosing `n=[0,0,1]` or `n=[1/np.sqrt(3), 1/np.sqrt(3), 1/np.sqrt(3)]` the matrix becomes unitary.

```
# Matrix taken from
# https://docplayer.org/117986458-Die-symmetriegruppen-so-3-und-su-2.html (p. 11, equation 46)
# https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/archive/fileadmin/lehre/teilchen/ws1011/SO3SU2.pdf (p. 8, equation 50)

def rn_su2(theta, n):
    n1 = n[0]
    n2 = n[1]
    n3 = n[2]
    return Operator([
        [np.cos(theta/2) - 1j*n3*np.sin(theta/2), -1j*(n1 - 1j*n2)*np.sin(theta/2)],
        [-1j*(n1 + 1j*n2)*np.sin(theta/2), np.cos(theta/2) + 1j*n3*np.sin(theta/2)]
    ], input_dims=(2, 1), output_dims=(2, 1))

# Magnitude of the vector n must be 1
n = [0,0,1]
n = [1/np.sqrt(3), 1/np.sqrt(3), 1/np.sqrt(3)]

# Debug: check if the matrix is unitary
mat = np.array(rn_su2(5, n))
# Compute A^dagger.A and see if it is identity matrix
mat = np.conj(mat.T).dot(mat)
print(mat)

# construct the operator
rotated = circuit.unitary(rn_su2(pi, n), 0)
```

I checked in the notebook [here at Github](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/bloch_sphere/rotate_su2_qiskit_eldar-sultanow.ipynb).

The rotation by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ around the $z$-axis can be performed as follows (for this I oriented myself to [this lecture note](https://www.phys.hawaii.edu/%7Eyepez/Spring2013/lectures/Lecture1_Qubits_Notes.pdf)):

```
rot_angle = pi/4
n = [0, 0, 1]
rot_operator = rn_su2(rot_angle, n)
rot_matrix = np.array(rot_operator)
start_vec = [1, 0, 0]

_bloch = Bloch()
_bloch.vector_color = ['blue', 'red']

sv = []
vec = start_vec
sv.append(vec)

spherical_vec = to_spherical(vec)
ϕ = spherical_vec[1]
θ = spherical_vec[2]
print(spherical_vec)

sx = msigma(1)
sy = msigma(2)
sz = msigma(3)
M_q = (np.sin(θ)*np.cos(ϕ)*sx + np.sin(θ)*np.sin(ϕ)*sy + np.cos(θ)*sz)
U_n = np.eye(2)*np.cos(rot_angle/2) -1j*(n[0]*sx+n[1]*sy+n[2]*sz)*np.sin(rot_angle/2)
M_q_rotated = U_n*M_q*np.matrix(U_n).H
print(M_q_rotated)
cos_θ_rotated = float(N(re(M_q_rotated[0,0])))
θ_rotated = np.arccos(cos_θ_rotated)
print(θ_rotated)

#e^(ix) = cos(x) + i*sin(x)
#see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity
temp = float(N(re(M_q_rotated[1,0])))
temp = temp/np.sin(θ_rotated)
ϕ_rotated = np.arccos(temp)
print(ϕ_rotated)

vec = np.array(to_cartesian([1, θ_rotated, ϕ_rotated]))
sv.append(vec)

_bloch.add_vectors(sv)
_bloch.render()
```

which looks as follows:

[image]

Note that in the code above some polishing still need to be done such as exception handling of corner cases (e.g. in trigonometric functions).